# Object Oriented design - how to nest one class into another class

Tags: java, database-design, architecture, entity

I come from the world of relational databases and I find myself having to create my first object oriented program, and despite studying, I just cannot grasp how to do the most basic things.

I have defined a `Product` class (`int id`, `String productName`, `double price`...), with its methods and attributes, and a `ProductFamily` class (`String familyName`, `String costCenter`...) with its own methods and attributes.

How should link/embed both classes? I've tried using subclasses with the "extends" keyword, but this just seems to inherit the methods from one to another. It doesn't let me instantiate a new product object into a given product family.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a field to your Product class, which is an object to a ProductFamily class. By adding a method getProductFamily() in your Product class you can return the product familys for the specific product.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but how do I create the constructor to add a field which is in turn a class? public Product (int id, String productName, double price...) {}

Comment: public Product (int id, String productName, double price, ProductFamily family) {}

If you create a new product: Product p = new Product(1, "whatever", 1.0, someresoure) where "someresource" is an object to an existing ProductFamily.

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this, assuming there is a 1 to N relationship between `ProductFamily` and `Product` classes:

```
class ProductFamily{

    private List<Product> products;

    //add all other members and getters and setters
}
```

Whenever you want to add a new `Product` to a specific `ProductFamily` instance, you can get the list of `Product` from the getter and add to it. There could be another method in the `ProductFamily` class that lets you add a new `Product` instance to the list.

```
 class ProductFamily{

    private List<Product> products;

    //add all other members and getters and setters

    public void addProduct(Product newProduct){
        this.products.add(newProduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a 1 to many relationship. I really don't know how to add a new Product to a ProductFamily in this way, I added the line you suggested but... I suppose this has been answered a million times, but can't find the answer or anywhere to read about it. Thanks!!

Comment: @HernánRuiz I edited the answer to show you the method

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry for being such a newbie/an idiot, but how do I instantiate a new Product within a Product family in this way?

Comment: You have to instantiate the product object using its constructor and then pass that instance to the product family instance using the addProduct method

Answer (score 0):

You can only extend one class in Java. You can do that in many classes. If you want to extend multiple classes with the same function names i would use interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you come from the world of relational databases, you may have a firm grasp on several interrelated concepts, including relational joins, data normalization, logical data independence, self describing data, ACID transactions, and concurrency control.  It's difficult for the beginner to truly grasp the power and simplicity of each of these concepts without being a little familiar with all of them.  Believe it or not, object modeling experts don't find it easy to grasp each of these concepts by just comparing them to things they already know.

A similar thing happens when you first begin to learn object modeling.  Three interrelated concepts are inheritance, encapsulation, and polymorphism.  None of these make much sense without some grasp of the other two.  They all work together to make a system that is both powerful and simple.

Resist the temptation to consider the object model to be like the relational model, only without some features.  That's an oversimplification of the object model.  The truth is that each of these modeling paradigms was an enormous advance in the state of the art of modeling, some forty to fifty years ago.  Each of them makes it a lot easier to think about existing systems or proposed systems, yet to be built.

**But they are not like each other**, and neither one was derived from the other.

If you are going to start with relational think,  here's where to start.  Decide whether the relationship between Product and ProductFamily is a HAS-A relationship or an IS-A relationship.  HAS-A relationships are easily modeled (relationally) using separate tables and foreign keys.  In terms of objects, they are best modeled as separate classes, with a reference from one to the other.  IS-A relationships are different.  For an example, a pet store might have cats, dogs, birds, and snakes, but they are all pets.  there are some attributes or methods that only pertain to birds or to cats, but there are others that pertain  to all of them.

The nearest analogue to Superclass/Subclass in Relational modeling is not in the Relational model, but in the Extended Entity Relationship model. Here, there is a concept called Generalization/Specialization.  A cat, dog, bird, or snake is a specialization of the generalization pet.  It's an IS-A relationship.  If Generalization/specialization makes sense to you in the case at hand,  then subclasses and inheritance is going to serve you well.  If not,  then you'd best not to try to use subclasses here.

There are literally hundreds of questions here in StackOverflow asked by people who are accustomed to object modeling,  and want to know how to accomplish IS-A relationships with SQL tables.  The latest example is right next to your question, and is called [Schedule Join Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083905/schedule-join-multiple-tables).  For those people, there is a tag [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance).  The hard thing for them to get is how the relational model can do anything without the concept of inheritance.  Your problem is the opposite.  How and when to use inheritance to make life simpler than it is in a relational schema. And when not to use inheritance.

You need to decide whether Product and ProductFamily are a case where inheritance is useful.  Again,  if it's a HAS-A relationship,  forget subclasses and inheritance.  If it's an IS-A relationship,  inheritance is the key to an easy solution.  In order to do meaningful operations on the superclass, you are either going to have to limit yourself to operations that are meaningful to the superclass,  or you are going to have to learn how to build polymorphic  operations. It's a lot of learning, but there is a lot of value at the end of the road.